# c++11 unsigned char becoming int when using operator =

Tags: c++, c++11, int, clang

c++11 unsigned char becoming int when using operator =, example code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    class uchar {
    public:
        uchar(unsigned char c)
        : c_(c) {

        }
    private:
        unsigned char c_;
    };
    const unsigned char c2 = 5;
    uchar c1(5);

    // output: 1 1
    std::cout << sizeof(c1) << " " << sizeof(c2) << std::endl; 
    // compile error: invalid operands to binary expression ('uchar' and 'int')
    std::cout << (c1 == c2) << std::endl; 
}
```

can somebody explain why the above error? why does clang report `c2` as an int?

> using clang++ v6.0 -std=c++11

Comment: `uchar` is your class. you need to overload `operator==`

Comment: Not quite sure why c2 is considered to be an int in the error. But to fix the problem, you can override the `operator==` between a `uchar` and an unsigned char. Alternatively, you can replace uchar by an alias (with the `using` keyword).

Comment: Cannot reproduce - g++ gives `error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'main(int, char**)::uchar' and 'const unsigned char')`

Comment: @NeilButterworth Use clang 6.0 or lower: https://wandbox.org/permlink/v7J38Y6ME3uPKE1Q

Comment: i kind think when declare uchar(unsigned char c) , there will be a implimit conversion from `unsigned char` to `uchar`, thus the `operator==` should be working...

Comment: What is the question? Why compiler identifies `uchar` as an `int` or why you cannot compare `unsigned char` with `uchar` directly?

Comment: @TerryWu There is, but you cannot compare two `uchar`s since you did not define a comparison operator.

Comment: @TerryWu Why would there be an implicit conversion, `uchar` could contain anything?

Comment: OK, i got the comparison not working due to lack of comparison operator. then why clang report `c2` as an `int` ?

Comment: "why does clang report c2 as an int" because of integral promotion.

Comment: @n.m. Integral promotion shouldn't be applied here because the process fails during overload resolution.

Comment: @xskxzr The standard says nothing about integral promotions in programs that contain errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can somebody explain why the above error ?

First of all you cannot directly compare `uchar` with `unsigned char` because they are 2 different types and no implicit conversion exists. You can overload `operator==` but instead you could provide conversion operator which will represent your `uchar` as `unsigned char` whenever appropriate:

```
operator unsigned char()
{
    return c_;
}
```

This way it will do [what you expect](https://ideone.com/ZnfpYZ).

> why does clang report c2 as an int?

As for why Clang thinks that `unsigned char` is an `int`, it looks like a bug as it [doesn't do this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oNknVVq469NM1ZQw) in later versions.